# Where jmeter matrics will be stored?

Tags: jmeter

I want to know where jmeter matrices will be stored in jmeter. Whenever I run a test it will give some matrices as output. I can analyze them using listeners. I will push data's to influx db and dashboard them in grafana. Where can i see the process (data transformation from jmeter to influxdb). and from where the listenrs are getting the metrics?? Where the metrics will be stored in jmeter?? Can we get any log files??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to local metrics which you can observe using listeners - when you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

The metrics are being stored in the `result.jtl` file which is by default a normal [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) which can be opened by any [JMeter Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), any text editor, any spreadsheet tool like [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or [MS Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel)

With regards to Influx DB and Grafana integration - JMeter will send metrics to the location which you specify in the [Backend Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener), normally it should be live Influx DB instance

Comment: Thanks a lot , It is  in case of non gui mode execution what about GUI mode execution??

Comment: When you run a JMeter test in GUI mode the metrics are being stored **in memory**. Also there is a possibility to configure listener(s) to store  the results into a file. However be aware that running a test in GUI mode causes huge overhead and main ruin your test so use it wisely (i.e. for development and debugging purposes only), when it comes to "real" load test execution make sure you're following advices from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)  guide